# incrementing time value by 15 minutes

Tags: php, time

I have value 10:00:00 in my mor_start which is of type time in mysql database i want it to increment by 15 minutes.

```
$tim=$values['mor_start'];
$date = date('H:i:s', strtotime($tim));
echo $date;
```

the above code displays 10:00:00

but when i try to increment the time by the following code i get error : Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered

```
$tim=$values['mor_start'];
$date = date('H:i:s', strtotime("+15 minutes",$tim));
echo $date;
```

Comment: is $tim a correct timestamp ?

Comment: As your first example indicates that $tim is a string and not a timestamp, `$date = date('H:i:s', strtotime("+15 minutes",strtotime($tim)));`

Comment: yep, i confirm that Mark Baker is right

Comment: this doesn't really have a lot to do with mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark Baker said (he should deserve the answer) one correct solution is replace the calculation by this :

```
strtotime("+15 minutes",strtotime($tim)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `strtotime()` multiple times is a little overkill. Code with [DateTime extension](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) is a faster example (and ofc more beautiful), like [this demo](https://eval.in/60462):

```php
echo date_create('10:00:00')->modify('+15 minute')->format('H:i:s');
```

Test [this demo](https://eval.in/60467) on your localhost and see the difference. My result on `1e6` loops is:

```
add15min_v1() has looped 1000000x times in 23.47sec.
add15min_v2() has looped 1000000x times in  6.81sec.
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$date = date('H:i:s', strtotime("+15 minutes", strtotime($tim)));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: $date = date('H:i:s', strtotime("+15 minutes",strtotime($tim)));  this worked for me !!

Answer (score -1):

```
$tim=$values['mor_start'];
$date = date("H:i:s", strtotime("+15 minutes",strtotime($tim)));
echo $date;
```

This should work.